# How to get value from then in javascript

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs, react-native-xml2js

i have maybe stupid question. 
I m trying to save XML file which i load through xml2js with readfile function.
I want to store file content string to global variable but i dont know how to get from promise then a value.

```
var myval;
var simpleStore = function(value){
   myval = value;
}
var myvariable = RNFS.readFile(APPLICATION_HISTORY_DIRECTORY, 'utf8').then(simpleStore);
```

Comment: Where you have defined this code, is it inside component where you have access to `state` or it is outside of component?

Comment: Its outside of component.Before export default class and after imports....

Comment: What value you are getting in `myval`, the way you have handled promise it looks good, `myval` should have the required value. BTW do we want to make `myval` available to entire APP?

Comment: I want to view content of file in component. myval is available in one file where i want to display it. I m getting undefined in myval.

Comment: `myval` is `undefined` inside `simpleStore` function? Can you share a bit more code?

Comment: No i mean outside but i cant use other functions inside so i cant work with text from file...